# drools 6 rules java level

Tags: java, java-8, drools

I try to use switch like this in drl file

```
switch(monthTxt){
    case "demo1":
        month = "01";
        break;
    case "demo2":
        month = "02";
        break;
```

drool compiler show me this error

```
Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7.
```

I try to set java level in this way but nothing change

```
container = services.newKieContainer( services.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId() );
kieBase = container.getKieBase();

kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
KieSessionConfiguration ksc = kieSession.getSessionConfiguration();
ksc.setProperty("drools.dialect.java.lngLevel", "1.8");
ksc.setProperty("drools.dialect.java.compiler.lngLevel", "1.8");
```